# Post in a facebook app as my page?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm a little bit confused right now. But I think I'm making it more complicated than it is actually :) It's about posting out of a Facebook app. I have a Facebook page and I'm about to develop an app which should be integrated in that page. The purpose is to make the page more attractive and memorable. The app is about the content the page contributes. The problem is (I've alredy read some questions about that, but still I don't get it), if I post on a users' wall, I post as the app and not as the page.

It is possible to post on a users' wall after requesting their permission (publish_stream) and also on to post on a page the user administrates (manage_page). Am I right so far? But is there a way to post as my page within my app? Can I post as a one of my app users on a wall with any permission? I thought about if I start to use my app as my page, maybe then I can post as my page?

It may sound a bit awkward, but I hope anyone can help me. At least to tell me that I'm dreaming of something which wouldn't be possible anytime (because of security issues i.e.).

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Post to Facebook application page as APPLICATION user](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4530177/post-to-facebook-application-page-as-application-user)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot post as your page, users in your application can post to their walls or your applications page. In fact when building your app, if you are using Facebook as a page and try to refresh your App from your URL you will get errors... if you need help starting your app with the functions i have mentioned, visit this link: http://www.epixseo.com/index.php/facebook-php-3-3-1-and-javascript-sdk-graph-api-tutorial/

Comment: But isn't it possible to post to the wall on my page with my access_token, because I'm an admin? The idea is that I don't wanna have two ways of traffic, one on the wall of my app and the other one on the wall of my page. The focus should stay on the page. So the best case would be: First of all, the posts I create in my app should be posted on my page and secondly the posts should link to my page and not the app :)
Impossible?

Comment: Yes you can post to your applications page or any of your pages for that matter, you just cannot post as the page. The example I posted includes this functionality